# Stripe send payment to customers' bank account in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm working on a POS app where users can buy things from owners. How can I send the money directly from the user to the owner in nodejs?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Stripe Connect in order to send funds to another account with Stripe.

Stripe Connect is a huge topic and needs lots of research into account types and fund flows: https://stripe.com/docs/connect.